# c++ std::normal_distribution gives inconsistent random numbers when restoring from file

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm writing a Monte Carlo simulation and implemented checkpointing. I want to obtain the exact same results, whether or not I restart the simulation from a checkpoint or continue beyond it. However, I encountered some weird behavior with `std::normal_distribution`:

I am using a `std::mt19937 rng;` as the RNG and seed it to a fixed number. I draw a certain amount of random numbers via both `std::uniform_real_distribution uniform;` and `std::normal_distribution normal;`. Then, I write the state of the rng to an `ofstream os`:

```
os << rng << endl;
os << <some other stuff>...
```

Immediately afterwards, I draw a couple more numbers:

```
os << uniform(rng) << endl;
os << uniform(rng) << endl;
os << uniform(rng) << endl;
os << normal(rng) << endl;
os << normal(rng) << endl;
os << normal(rng) << endl;
os << uniform(rng) << endl;
os << uniform(rng) << endl;
os << uniform(rng) << endl;
```

I get the following output:

```
0.727133
0.215537
0.516879
-2.12532
0.314652
1.78136
0.511111
0.83119
0.637067
```

If I however restart from the checkpoint, i.e. initializing the generator from an `ifstream is`:

```
is >> rng;
is >> <some other stuff>...
```

and drawing the same 9 random numbers (3 uniform, 3 normal, 3 uniform), I get:

```
0.727133
0.215537
0.516879
0.314652
1.78136
1.28201
0.637067
0.298175
0.802607
```

You see, that the uniform numbers are identical until a normal number is drawn after which the states of the rng differs. Stepping through with `gdb` confirmed that.

Comment: Could it just be a bug in your code? Can you make a self-contained, reproducible example (e.g. using a string stream for the serialization)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think he doesn't realize that `normal` has internal state.

Comment: Indeed, I did not. I guess it is understandable knowing that the Box-Mueller method generates normal random numbers in pairs. (Not that Box-Mueller is necessarily what is implemented, but I suppose the principle is the same.) Thanks, man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look where `0.637067` is in the two outputs. You'll notice that the normal distribution had to pull more numbers from the rng when restored than it did when not restored. That's because it had entropy when you checkpointed.

You must either save or reset the state of `normal`. I'd suggest calling [reset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/reset) on `normal` as part of the checkpoint process.

Comment: I ended up just storing the distributions rather than calling `reset`. The checkpointing is done based on wall clock time, so it should not disturb the sequence of random numbers when the goal is to obtain deterministic results (for debugging). Thanks for the quick response, I was starting to doubt my sanity with this issue.